# Expand a function into a series (approximation without ever knowing the unknowns)

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, approximation

I am having the following problem:
We have the unknowns x and y for which we know the following:
`x/(x+y) = k` where k is a real known number. We also have some known variables a and b which are real numbers and each one of them is less than x and y.
Is there a possible way to expand the following expression into a series or a mathematical approximation with x and y separated from a and b?

```
(x+a)/(x+y+a+b)
```

For example something like: `k/(a+b)+2*k/(a+b)+...`
In other words, would it be possible to know an approximate result of this expression without ever knowing x and y?

Comment: Is $a<x$, $b<y$ or are $a$ and $b$ both less than $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%28x%2Ba%29%2F%28x%2By%2Ba%2Bb%29

Comment: a<x and b<y @Sal

Comment: @Christian I don't see how these particular series expansions can help in the evaluation of the expression